# OOTB Site Collection Map WebPart SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-server, site-collection, data-view-web-part

Is there any OOTB web part in SharePoint that can pull out the list of all Site Collections present in the Web Application?

I have multiple site collections under my domain.

```
http://test.domain.com/SC1

http://test.domain.com/SC2

http://test.domain.com/SC3
```

I want show all Site Collection's Titles and Urls on root site `http://test.domain.com/` .

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB webpart available for this activity. But you can create a custom Web Part for this.

Programmatically find out the number of site-collections within a web application.  [SPWebApplication.Sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.sites.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) would help you get the site-collection present inside web application.

Check these for more info:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d271da25-57f4-4f59-a34d-fd06bc4c8ce6/use-web-part-to-show-all-site-collections-current-user-is-a-member-of?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561992/how-to-get-all-site-collections-in-a-web-application

Comment: Thank you Waqas for reply. Unfortunately i am bound not to use any programming approach. Otherwise getting all this stuff with code is quite workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of Search and query result Webpart that concentrates on Websites that are sitecollections. Remember the Limit of 50 entries that could be shown... if you have more entries than you have to configure paging to the Webpart ;)